# Xpath радиокнопка

Tags: xpath

Как прописать путь к кнопке
Пытаюсь сделать это так "//input[text() ='ComboTV']/preceding-sibling::span"
Но не работает
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di66k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
//input[@id='combotv']/following-sibling::span
```

Или так, если важен поиск именно по отображаемому тексту:

```
//label[child::a[normalize-space(text())='ComboTV']]/child::span[@class='checkmark']
```